# Flex DataGrid: Show only rows which have specific value in one column

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have an ArrayCollection which is a dataProvider to the DataGrid. The ArrayCollection may look like that:

```
{Name: Bob; LikesIceCream:YES},
{Name: Carl; LikesIceCream:NO},
{Name: Ed; LikesIceCream:NO}
```

I want to have a checkbox, which would make the DataGrid show either all people when it is checked, or only those who have a property LikesIceCream:NO when it is not checked. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Add a filter to your ArrayCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filterFunction property of ArrayCollection.

Write your own function that will filter collection:

> ```
> function myFilterFunction(item: Object): Boolean 
> {
>    var result: Boolean = true;
>    if (!checkBox.selected)  
>    {
>       result = (item.LikesIceCream == "Yes");
>    }
>    return result;
> }
> ```

Set collection filterFunction property

> collection.filterFunction = myFilterFunction;

Refresh collection initially and after check box change

> collection.refresh();